# Layer-2, static forwarding on a Juniper SRX?

Tags: juniper, mac-address

I'm really new to Juniper, so I apologize if this is n00b question. I do, however, appreciate your guidance!

Here is what I want to do: all traffic on `ge0.0.0` and `ge0.0.1` is to be redirected to `fe0.0.2-7`, but I want to ensure that all traffic with the same MAC destination address is always sent to the same `fe`.

In an IBM Nortel (HSSM), I would use a layer-2, static forwarding database, but I can't find an equivalent for Juniper, at least on my old tinker test device. I've looked into defining a VLAN for each `fe`, and then adding the MAC addresses to the VLAN (`set static vlan [vlan-name] mac [mac-address] next-hop [interface]`), but it seems like there should be a more elegant way to address (har har) the issue. Thoughts?

Comment: Yes I realise that over subscription could be a real problem. This is a personal experiment, not a real world implementation.

Comment: The 'set vlan static ...' command creates a static layer two forwarding entry. I fail to see exactly what you are trying to achieve. Could you provide some more details?

Comment: Gerben, I'm trying to do that same basic thing without binding to a vlan. The command that I referenced needs a vlan defined for each fe. That's fine for an srx device where I only have 8 ports but I can't imagine trying to manage that on something bigger like an MX960 or the like. I want to create a forwarding rule that takes any given MAC 00:00:00:00:00:01 and forward it directly to a given port 'n'. Does that help? As to real world implications, this is more of an academic question.  I can do this thing with one device, how do I do it with this other one.

Comment: You can have all those interfaces in the same vlan, you just have to mention the vlan in the command because there is an ethernet-switching table per vlan.